# How to share inbox folder in Zimbra mail for Public View?

Tags: email, networking, sharing, zimbra

I want to share a mail inbox to everyone for read-only mode but in sharing options The public sharing (View only mode) is faded by default. How to enable this option ? I do have access to admin console. 
The screenshot for my problem is :- https://www.dropbox.com/s/88jwco66nt3wdl4/Untitled.png

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, to share mail folders public. This is only posseble for other iteams like calendar etc. Sorry.